# Disable button until all required fields are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 95 forms fields, some of which are mandatory and some of which are optional. I want to disable the submit button until all of the required fields are completed.

There are a lot of solutions out there but I am looking for one that will scan for the required flag in the input as I really don't want to have to list through all 95 fields if I can help it.

Is this possible with jQuery or something?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: have you used any jquery validation plugin?

Comment: @DharaParmar No, I am using Foundations data-abide

Comment: have you first tried using the `required` attribute on the required input fields? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required

Comment: @varunsharma I tried your code and can't get it working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @john. Your jquery.min.js is not working .

Comment: @john. If my answer is right then voting up helps to others.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input[required]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Username<br />
    <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" required /><br />
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="password" required /><br />
    Confirm Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" required /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required/><br /> 
  name<br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/> optional<br />     
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
  
</form>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Varuna Sharma - thanks but this is for all fields, I just want to disable the button for required fields.

Comment: @JohnHiggins for required fields you can use  $('form > input[required]').each......

Comment: Sorry varun but its not that good to check if ($(this).val() == '')  by this way if the user type spaces the code will assume it that is not empty so you can use if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
                    $(this).val('');
                    empty = true;
                }         ....... Good Luck man :)

Comment: @varunsharma - I tried the code above and the button is disabled even if all fields are completed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @john. Check your jquery.min.js. It is included or not?

Comment: @Varun - your code on it's own works but when I apply it to mine it does not. Not sure why

Comment: @varun - jquery,min.js is included

Comment: @john. what issue  came?Disabled button not enable?

Comment: @varun - yes - even if all fields are completed the button will not enable

Comment: @John. Check your jquery.min.js file. I am sure jquery.min.js file not working fine. Once you can put direct cdn link of jquery. Like-: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @varun - I think I found the problem. My button has a type of button and not submit as it's used to call the Stripe payment javascript. Is it possible to amend your code so that it works with a type of button?

Comment: @John. Ok. Good Luck.

Comment: @varun - I have select boxes and also textarea's too. I am guessing that's what's causing the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110719/discussion-between-varun-sharma-and-john-higgins).